# Java : How can I test save method?

Tags: java

I have a following save method, but I dont know how to verify that the method is working correctly. How can I verify it in Test Class ??

```
 static void saveFile(List<String> contents, String path){

   File file = new File(path);
   PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file)));

   for(String data : contents){
      pw.println(data);
   }
 }
```

Sorry, contents is not String, but List. But is there no need to make test class ?? because it is constructed by tested java method.

Comment: create another method called loadFile and read the written data and verify the contents are the same in both situations

Comment: Why you would like to test Java Standard classes? There is no logic in your method that you should test.

Comment: You are not closing the PrintWriter in your method, so it won't completely write all lines to the file. Also, you do realise there's already a standard method `Files.write` that does the same thing, don't you?

Comment: Do you want to test whether the file was written correctly at runtime? Or do you want to detect your own failures while coding your application?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `FileWriter` from you method like this

```
static void saveFile(List<String> contents, Writer writer){
   PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(writer));

   for(String data : contents){
      pw.println(data);
   }

   pw.flush();
}
```

In your [JUnit](http://junit.org) test method use `StringWriter` for checking your saving logic

```
@Test
void testWriter() {
   StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
   saveFile(Arrays.asList("test content", "test content2"), writer);
   assertEquals("test content\ntest content2\n", writer.toString());
}
```

and in your real code

```
...
Writer writer = new FileWriter(new File(path));
saveFile(Arrays.asList("real content", "real content2"), writer);
...
```

Comment: writer.toString() won't return the written content

Comment: @Pooya It will. Read [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html#toString%28%29) carefully

Comment: @Pooya also you should use `writer.flush()` to make sure your content really written to writer. It's true both for test and real usage.

Answer (score 1):

For testing, you may consider a test framework such as jUnit and write your test case. In your specific case, you could write something as follows:

```
public class TestCase {

    @Test
    public void test() throws IOException {
        String contents = "the your content";
        String path = "the your path";

        // call teh metod
        saveFile(contents, path);

        // tacke a reference to the file
        File file = new File(path);

        // I assert that the file is not empty
        Assert.assertTrue(file.length() > 0);

        // I assert that the file content is the same of the contents variable
        Assert.assertSame(Files.readLines(file, Charset.defaultCharset()).stream().reduce("", (s , s2) -> s+s2),contents);
    }


    static void saveFile(String contents, String path) throws IOException {

        File file = new File(path);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file)));

        pw.println(contents);
    }
}
```

In this way, you have a framework to check if the your code works as you expect. If this isn't sufficient, you should look into a mock framework such as Mockito.

Comment: You don't need to test real file writing but logic of writing.

Comment: I agree with you Andriy, the my answer was as technical support, in other words if you want perform a test case on a method as in the question may be a good choice select a test framework and in my answare show a way for use the jUnit api. just it.